# How to fit the chart on div when resize the window?

Tags: highcharts

I used below code to resize the chart when window resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{    
    chart.setSize(
       $(document).width(), 
       $(document).height()/2,
       false
    );   
});
```

For RangeSlection buttons i have displayed in middle of the chart. I used Jugal given in Sebastians link `http://jsfiddle.net/SPhYd/`
and modified button width dynamically.

var leftPosition = this.chart.plotLeft+150

( instead of 150 i have passed button width)

When i resize the chart, the chart gets cutoff in ipad portrait mode and also the range selection buttons(3yr,10yr,ytd) coming out of the chart. 
[image]
Can you suggest how to fit the range selection buttons in middle of the chart always and also adjust the chart within a div based on winow resize?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider of using `width / height` (container size) in percent? Then it will be responsive.

http://jsfiddle.net/3tjhk/

Try to resize window.

Comment: I need to show the small chart in my page. so i used 400px.Above code is not working for me. As i used media queries for #Container id.